# Apache Ignite - Unmatched Argument

Tags: tensorflow, cluster-computing, ignite, gridgain

I'm trying to create a tensorflow cluster on top of the Ignite cluster in my local multi-node environment.
I followed the tutorials and found tried the following command:

```
./ignite-tf.sh start TESTDATA models python /usr/local/grid/cifar10_main.py
```

This gives me an unmatched error as follows:

```
Unmatched argument:
Usage: ignite-tf [-hV] [-c=<cfg>] [COMMAND]
Apache Ignite and TensorFlow integration command line tool that allows to
start, maintain and stop distributed deep learning utilizing Apache Ignite
infrastructure and data.
  -c, --config=<cfg>   Apache Ignite client configuration.
  -h, --help           Show this help message and exit.
  -V, --version        Print version information and exit.
Commands:
  start   Starts a new TensorFlow cluster and attaches to user script process.
  stop    Stops a running TensorFlow cluster.
  attach  Attaches to running TensorFlow cluster (user script process).
  ps      Prints identifiers of all running TensorFlow clusters.
```

I'm not sure which is the umatched argument. Need help getting this to work.

Comment: What Ignite version are you using?

Comment: I am using the Grid Gain Community version which comes with ignite-tf. The official ignite package doesn't include it.

Comment: What version of GGCE? I can execute this specific command with GGCE without getting "unmatched argument"

Comment: I'm running GGCE version 8.7.24.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded this specific version and tried to run this command, I don't get any error messages, it would try to start a node:

```
 311842 pts/12   S+     0:00  |   |   \_ bash ./ignite-tf.sh start TESTDATA models python /usr/local/grid/cifar10_main.py
 311902 pts/12   Sl+    0:03  |   |       \_ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//bin/java -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Xms1g -Xmx1g -server -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -DIGNITE_QUIET=false -DIGNITE_SUCCESS_FILE=/home/user/Downloads/gridgain-community-8.7.24/work/ignite_success_20e882c5-5b64-4d0a-b7ed-9587c08a0e44 -DIGNITE_HOME=/home/user/Downloads/gridgain-community-8.7.24 -DIGNITE_PROG_NAME=./ignite-tf.sh -cp /home/user/Downloads/gridgain-community-8.7.24/libs/*:/home/user/Downloads/gridgain-community-8.7.24/libs/ignite-control-utility/*:/home/user/Downloads/gridgain-community-8.7.24/libs/ignite-indexing/*:/home/user/Downloads/gridgain-community-8.7.24/libs/ignite-opencensus/*:/home/user/Downloads/gridgain-community-8.7.24/libs/ignite-spring/*:/home/user/Downloads/gridgain-community-8.7.24/libs/licenses/*:/home/user/Downloads/gridgain-community-8.7.24/libs/optional//ignite-tensorflow/*:/home/user/Downloads/gridgain-community-8.7.24/libs/optional//ignite-slf4j/* org.apache.ignite.tensorflow.submitter.JobSubmitter start TESTDATA models python /usr/local/grid/cifar10_main.py
```